# Trying to install the quickdraw package in R

Tags: r, package, warnings, quickdraw

Currently I am trying to use the quickdraw package in R. So far I tried `install.packages("quickdraw")` but got a warning saying `Warning in install.packages : package ‘quickdraw’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)`. Anyone know what version of R supports the use of this package and how I can change my R version to that respective version? Thanks

Comment: Is it the same as this?: `install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("huizezhang-sherry/quickdraw")` see: https://rdrr.io/github/huizezhang-sherry/quickdraw/#vignettes

Comment: Only packages that are on CRAN can be installed with `install.packages()` and that package doesn't seem to have ever been on CRAN. Use Peter's code to install from that github repository.